# Why was my post flagged as spam by a bot?

Tags: support

Why?
[Family tree for edible plants?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11049/family-tree-for-edible-plants/11052#11052)
It answers the OP with a non-commercial link.

Answer (score 6):

Obviously because you are using a temblast email adress (the site advertised which was announced). Also probably because your answer contains not much more than the link as a pointer to another website, which is not welcome here. Answers should be given here with links and references only serving for further reading.